# I can only boot in recovery mode and can't get into my desktop. Is there a way to reset to original installation?

Tags: recovery-mode, reset

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 for about a month, and I broke it. I'm not sure what I did, and want to reset it to the original installation. I currently dual boot with Windows, and that works, but can only get to recovery mode in Ubuntu.

Comment: Try this [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to reinstall the distro to the same partitions, so will be an clean install of it.
What distro you're using? If an old pc i suggest you try Xubuntu for more compatibility with older hardware. Let me know :)